# |z-1| = |z +i| On Which Sets Of Points For z In The Complex Plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

On Which Sets Of Points For z In The Complex Plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $ z= x + iy $ an you will get $(x-1)^2 + y^2  = x^2 + (y+1)^2 $. Now try to simplify this. (after simplifying: $ x+y = 0$)

Comment: | x-1 + iy| = | x + i(y+1) |
Can i solve it this way some how?

Comment: Yes, of course. Now use the definition of the complex module $ |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $ for both sides. Then square the whole equality and you will get the expression from my answer.

Comment: i see thats what you did before now thanks.

after simplifying i get: -2x = y^2 + y

im not sure what you mean by (after simplifying: x+y=0x+y=0)

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere. The next step after the equality from my answer is: $ x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2y + 1 $. After canceling the same variables you get $ -2x = 2y $, or $ x= -y $. So, the set you looking for is a set of complex numers $(x,y)$ witch satisfy the condition that $x= -y $.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: the equation is that of the set of points that are equidistant from $z=1$ and $z=-i$

Comment: more hints please

Comment: It is therefore the perpendicular bissector sometimes called mediatrix of the segment joining the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$

Comment: Keep in mind $|z-1|$ is the distance to $(1,0)$ and $|z+i|$ is the distance to $-i$ i.e $(0,-1)$

Comment: So i have two points (1,0) and (0,1).
How can i find the sets of points that are equidistant?

Comment: It is elementary geometry : it is the line perpendicular to the segment passing through its midpoint. It is called the perpendicular bissector or mediatrix of the segment. In our case it is the line of equation $x=-y$. Just draw a figure.